# Determine if an executable is running

Tags: c#

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, but I'm trying to delete a binary file when it's not running, but if it's running, display a message box telling the user to close the program before deleting it. When I tried doing it, it ignores the message box and attempts to delete the file when it's running, obviously you can't do that so Visual Studio so it returns with this:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\cmctemp\lcpol\lcweb.exe' is denied.'

Not sure why it's not displaying the message box.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("lcweb.exe");
    if (pname.Length == 0)
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\cmctemp\lcpol\lcweb.exe"))
            File.Delete(@"C:\cmctemp\lcpol\lcweb.exe");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Please close the program before deleting!", "Information");
}
```

Comment: You probably want `Process.GetProcessesByName("lcweb")`

Comment: You should first check this process by ProcessInfo if it has length > 0 then you should prompt and delete if you message requirement is done by user

Comment: As @DavidG said, remove `.exe` from the process name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try do that:

```
  private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("lcweb");
        if (pname.Length == 0 && File.Exists(@"C:\cmctemp\lcpol\lcweb.exe"))
            File.Delete(@"C:\cmctemp\lcpol\lcweb.exe");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Please close the program before deleting!", "Information");
  }
```

The First change we removed ".exe" from **GetProcessByName**, and the second I just adjust your **if statement**.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed my problem. I'm still partially new at c#. :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that `lcweb.exe` is not a valid process name. From the docs for `Process.GetProcessesByName`https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx:

> *processName*: **The friendly name of the process.**

So you need the friendly name of the process. This is probably be the executable without the `.exe` suffix:

```
Process.GetProcessesByName("lcweb")
```

If you really need to find the process by the name of the executable, you will need to do something like this:

```
Process.GetProcesses()
    .Where(p => p.MainModule.ModuleName == "lcweb.exe")
```

However, you will need to ensure your app is 64bit or you will get an exception.

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't have to *check* if the file exists:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx

> If the file to be deleted does not exist, no exception is thrown.

There're many reasons why the file *can't be deleted*, that's why I suggest
try to `Delete` and in case of `IOException` ask the user

```
try {
  File.Delete("lcweb.exe"); 
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) {
  // Possible reasons: 
  //   1. The caller does not have the required permission.
  //   2. The file is an executable file that is in use. <- your case
  //   3. path is a directory.
  //   4. path specified a read-only file.

  // If we are sure that the case "2" can be the only reason
  MessageBox.Show("Please close the program before deleting!", "Information");
}
```

Comment: However, program flow using exceptions is just a little bit dirty.

Comment: @DavidG: we can't avoid it: `lcweb.exe` can be started at *any time* (e.g. just *after* the check).

Comment: @DavidG - `try/catch` are very appropriate here. Who cares about dirty if it ensures the program does not crash due to an unhandled Exception?

Comment: IMO, replacing a if/else statement with exception handling is not really a good practice - adding them during the deletion is a good idea, however.

Comment: I'm not saying don't wrap it in a try/catch, I'm just suggesting that using it as a means to determine program flow isn't ideal. I would say do the check first, *then* try to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs 2 fixes, first : don't do nested if/else without brackets

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("lcweb");
        if (pname.Length == 0)
        {
            if (File.Exists(@"C:\cmctemp\lcpol\lcweb.exe"))
                File.Delete(@"C:\cmctemp\lcpol\lcweb.exe");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please close the program before deleting!", "Information");
        }
    }
```

You made the `else` linked with the wrong if.

For the second fix, accordingly to DavidG's answer, Process.GetProcessesByName need the friendly name of the process which in your case seems to be "lcweb"

Comment: No, the bracketless `if` in OPs code is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Shenron It's your opinion if the brackets are wrong or not. Question is about something different then brackets so keep up to the topic.

Comment: @DavidG OP wants to display a messagebox when the program is running... the if blocks are nested in his code, so the messagebox will be shown if the file doesn't exists, not when it's running.

Comment: @gobes I know what the code is supposed to do. But it's the process name of `lcweb.exe` that is the problem.

Comment: @gobes Note I'm not saying that nested `if` blocks without brakcets is a good idea - I think they're horrible and difficult to read.

Comment: @DavidG OP says `Not sure why it's not displaying the message box` so I assumed his question was not about the exception, but about the messagebox not showing up, which is a problem of `if` nesting.

Answer (score -2):

Add brackets to separate your `if`:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("lcweb");
    if (pname.Length == 0)
    {
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\cmctemp\lcpol\lcweb.exe"))
            File.Delete(@"C:\cmctemp\lcpol\lcweb.exe");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please close the program before deleting!", "Information");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because adding an else underneath the nested if statement is treated as an else for the File.Exists check.

Comment: OP wants to display a messagebox when the program is running... the `if` blocks are nested in his code, so the messagebox will be shown if the program doesn't exists, not when it's running.